# dompdf stops unexpectedly after data collection with mysq

Tags: php, mysql, dompdf

I have a file that converts my MySQL data to PDF using dompdf it works fine but sometimes it just throws 500 error and nothing shows up and after a few moments works and sometimes I am supposed to put a clean back up for it to work. All the is collected successfully with mysql and php but at last some errors in converting the PDF dont know is it dompdf bug or problem with my code. Please check the code below and help me make a better world... I greatly appreciate your help :)

```
<?php


$idswitch = $_GET['id']; // id for viewing

// Below is optional, remove if you have already connected to your database.
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('...', '..', '..', '...');

$sql=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM si_invoices WHERE id='$idswitch'")or die(mysql_error());


$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);


$sample .= "<div style='font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background:#000000; width: 100%; color: #ffffff; padding: 4px; text-align: center; font-size: 120%;' >PROFOMA INVOICE: ID:100".$row['id']."</div>";

$sample .= "<div style='width:100%; height: 120px; background: #ffffff;'>";

$sample .= "<img src='logo-si.png' style='width: 250px; padding: 15px'>";

$sample .= "<div style='font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background:#000000; width: 100%; color: #ffffff; padding: 4px; text-align: center; font-size: 75%' >Interior Exterior General Signs LED Architectural & Modular Sign Systems Traffic & Safety Signs MV No. Plates</div><br>";

$sample .= "<div style='font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; position:absolute; top: 35px; left: 300px; width: 400px;  border-left: 2px solid #000000; padding-left: 10px; background: #ffffff; font-size: 85%'>

UBUNGO BUSINESS PARK-P.O.BOX 1965 - <br>DAR ES SALAAM-TANZANIA- +255 22 2866500 / 2860440 -<br>068444 422
E-MAIL: headsales@signindustries.co.tz - info@signindustries.co.tz - www.signindustries.co.tz
</div>";


$sample .= "</div>";

$sample .= "<div style='width:100%; margin-top: 15px;'>

<div style='float:left; width: 400px; height:margin-right: 10px;'>


<table style='width: 100%; height: 175px; border: 1px solid #000000; padding: 3px; font-size: 90%; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>
  <tr>
  <th align='left'></th>
    <th align='left'></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td width='30%'>Main Client:</td>
  <td width='65%' align='left' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>".$row['main_client']."</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <td width='30%'>Postal Address:</td>
  <td width='65%' align='left' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>".$row['postal_address']."</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <td width='30%'>Contact Person:</td>
  <td width='65%' align='left' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>".$row['contact_person']."</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <td width='30%'>Telephone / Cell:</td>
  <td width='65%' align='left' style='border: 1px solid #000000;' >".$row['cell_offc']."</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <td width='30%'>Office Location:</td>
  <td width='65%' align='left' style='border: 1px solid #000000;' >".$row['office_loc']."</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <td width='30%'>Email Address:</td>
  <td width='65%' align='left' style='border: 1px solid #000000;' >".$row['email_addr']."</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <td width='30%'>Job Title:</td>
  <td width='65%' align='left' style='border: 1px solid #000000;' >".$row['job_title']."</td>
  </tr>
  
  
  
</table>

</div>

<div style='float:right; width: 40%; border: '>

<table style='width: 100%; height: 175px; border: 1px solid #000000; padding: 3px; font-size: 90%; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>
  <tr>
  <th align='left'></th>
    <th align='left'></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan='2' align='center' style='background: #000000; color: #ffffff;'>Customer Tax Information:</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <td>TIN#:</td>
  <td align='left' style='border: 1px solid #000000;' >".$row['clnt_tin']."</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <td>VRN#</td>
  <td align='left' style='border: 1px solid #000000;' >".$row['clnt_vrn']."</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <td>VAT Exempted:</td>
  <td align='left' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>".$row['vat_expt']."</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <td>Exemption Cert</td>
  <td align='left' style='border: 1px solid #000000;' >".$row['expt_cert']."</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td colspan='2' align='center' style='background: #000000; color: #ffffff;'>Our Tax Information:</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>TIN#:</td>
  <td align='left' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>".$row['our_tin']."</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>VRN#:</td>
  <td align='left' style='border: 1px solid #000000;' >".$row['our_vrn']."</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div style='clear:both;'>
</div>
<div>
</div>
</div>";


$sample .= "<table style='width: 100%; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; ' >
  <tr>
  <th align='center' style='border: 1px solid #000000;' >Requested Date:</th>
    <th align='center' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>Requested By:</th>
  <th align='center' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>Sales Person:</th>
  </tr >
  <tr>
  <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>".$row['date_created']."</td>
  <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>".$row['prepared_by']."</td>
  <td align='center' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>".$row['sales_person']."</td>
  </tr>
</table>";


$idfk = $row['inv_code']; // id for viewing

$subtotl = $row['sub_totl']; // id for viewing
$vattotl = $row['vat_percent']; // id for viewing
$grandtotl = $row['grand_total']; // id for viewing

$dis_perc_sub = $row['dis_perc_sub']; // id for viewing

$lpouser = $row['lpo_user']; // id for viewing
$lpostatus = $row['lpo_status']; // id for viewing



$servername = "...";
$username = "...";
$password = "...";
$dbname = "....";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM itemsinv WHERE invidfk='$idfk' ORDER BY ln_no ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$count = 0;

$sample .= "<table cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1' style='width:100%; border: 1px solid black; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-top: 20px 0 0 0; 
th, td { padding: 5px;}' >
  <tr>
    <th align='center' style='background: #000000; color: #ffffff; '>No</th>
    <th align='center' style='background: #000000; color: #ffffff; '>Product Details</th>
    <th align='center' style='background: #000000; color: #ffffff; '>Price</th>
    <th align='center' style='background: #000000; color: #ffffff; '>Qty</th>
    <th align='center' style='background: #000000; color: #ffffff; '>Total</th>
  </tr>";

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        
        $count++;
        
$sample .= "<tr>
    <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>" .$count. "</td>
    <td style='border: 1px solid black;'><b>" . $row['productname']. "</b><br>" . $row['particulars']. "</td>
    <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>". $row['price']. "</td>
    <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>". $row['qty']. "</td>
    <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>". $row['item_total']. "</td>
  </tr>";
        
       
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$sample .= "<tr><td align='right' colspan='4'><b>Sub Total:</b></td><td align='left' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>".$subtotl."</td></tr>";
$sample .= "<tr><td align='right' colspan='4'><b>VAT Total:</b></td><td align='left' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>".$vattotl."</td></tr>";
$sample .= "<tr><td align='right' colspan='4'><b>Discount %:</b></td><td align='left' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>".$dis_perc_sub."</td></tr>";
$sample .= "<tr ><td align='right' colspan='4'><b>Grand Total:</b></td><td align='left' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>".$grandtotl."</td></tr>";

$sample .= "</table>";

$sample .= "<br><b style='font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 70%;'>Please read our terms and conditions by visiting our website. http://signindustries.co.tz</b>";

mysqli_close($conn);











// create pdf of invoice
$invoiceFileName = 'Invoice-'. $row["contact_name"]. '.pdf';
require_once 'dompdf/src/Autoloader.php';
Dompdf\Autoloader::register();
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml(html_entity_decode($sample));
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream($invoiceFileName, array("Attachment" => false)); 
?>
```

Error log below

```
Stack trace:
#0 /home/crmsignindustrie/public_html/crm/admins/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php(4870): Imagick->writeimage('/tmp/cpdf_img_e...')
#1 /home/crmsignindustrie/public_html/crm/admins/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php(4984): Cpdf->addImagePngAlpha('/home/crmsignin...', 45.265748031496, 737.92949241794, 187.5, 35.112359550562, 6)
#2 /home/crmsignindustrie/public_html/crm/admins/dompdf/src/Adapter/CPDF.php(864): Cpdf->addPngFromFile('/home/crmsignin...', 45.265748031496, 737.92949241794, 187.5, 35.112359550562)
#3 /home/crmsignindustrie/public_html/crm/admins/dompdf/src/Renderer/Image.php(110): Dompdf\Adapter\CPDF->image('/home/crmsignin...', 45.265748031496, 68.848148031496, 187.5, 35.112359550562, 'normal')
#4 /home/crmsignindustrie/public_html/crm/admins/dompdf/src/Renderer.php(293): Dompdf\Renderer\Image->render(Object(Dompdf\FrameDecorator\I in /home/crmsignindustrie/public_html/crm/admins/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php on line 4870
[06-Jul-2020 13:58:06 UTC] PHP Warning:  Version warning: Imagick was compiled against Image Magick version 1650 but version 1654 is loaded. Imagick will run but may behave surprisingly in Unknown on line 0
[06-Jul-2020 13:58:06 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ImagickException: WriteBlob Failed `/tmp/cpdf_img_QpfKj7.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1755 in /home/crmsignindustrie/public_html/crm/admins/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php:4870
Stack trace:
#0 /home/crmsignindustrie/public_html/crm/admins/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php(4870): Imagick->writeimage('/tmp/cpdf_img_Q...')
#1 /home/crmsignindustrie/public_html/crm/admins/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php(4984): Cpdf->addImagePngAlpha('/home/crmsignin...', 45.265748031496, 737.92949241794, 187.5, 35.112359550562, 6)
#2 /home/crmsignindustrie/public_html/crm/admins/dompdf/src/Adapter/CPDF.php(864): Cpdf->addPngFromFile('/home/crmsignin...', 45.265748031496, 737.92949241794, 187.5, 35.112359550562)
#3 /home/crmsignindustrie/public_html/crm/admins/dompdf/src/Renderer/Image.php(110): Dompdf\Adapter\CPDF->image('/home/crmsignin...', 45.265748031496, 68.848148031496, 187.5, 35.112359550562, 'normal')
#4 /home/crmsignindustrie/public_html/crm/admins/dompdf/src/Renderer.php(293): Dompdf\Renderer\Image->render(Object(Dompdf\FrameDecorator\I in /home/crmsignindustrie/public_html/crm/admins/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php on line 4870
[06-Jul-2020 13:59:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  Version warning: Imagick was compiled against Image Magick version 1650 but version 1654 is loaded. Imagick will run but may behave surprisingly in Unknown on line 0
[06-Jul-2020 13:59:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ImagickException: WriteBlob Failed `/tmp/cpdf_img_0wDRir.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1755 in /home/crmsignindustrie/public_html/crm/admins/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php:4870
Stack trace:
#0 /home/crmsignindustrie/public_html/crm/admins/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php(4870): Imagick->writeimage('/tmp/cpdf_img_0...')
#1 /home/crmsignindustrie/public_html/crm/admins/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php(4984): Cpdf->addImagePngAlpha('/home/crmsignin...', 45.265748031496, 737.92949241794, 187.5, 35.112359550562, 6)
#2 /home/host/public_html/crm/admins/dompdf/src/Adapter/CPDF.php(864): Cpdf->addPngFromFile('/home/crmsignin...', 45.265748031496, 737.92949241794, 187.5, 35.112359550562)
#3 /home/host/public_html/crm/admins/dompdf/src/Renderer/Image.php(110): Dompdf\Adapter\CPDF->image('/home/crmsignin...', 45.265748031496, 68.848148031496, 187.5, 35.112359550562, 'normal')
#4 /home/host/public_html/crm/admins/dompdf/src/Renderer.php(293): Dompdf\Renderer\Image->render(Object(Dompdf\FrameDecorator\I in /home/host/public_html/crm/admins/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php on line 4870
```

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Okay Let me upload the error log

Comment: I have updated my question and added the error log

Comment: anyone please help to guide me in debugging this problem

Comment: Have you checked this: `Version warning: Imagick was compiled against Image Magick version 1650 but version 1654 is loaded. Imagick will run but may behave surprisingly in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: No I havent I have checked everywhere decided to change the whole code really thanks for your suggestion Code Spirit!!